# Team Foundation Server TFS 2013 GIT branch permissions

Tags: git

Is there a way of restricting users access to GIT branch in TFS?

I would like to add a new user to my TFS project and allow him to access only one branch.

Comment: Define "access"?  Read?  See?  Push to?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deny access to the branch but you can deny pushes to the branch on the server.

In the web UI, go to

1. Code->Explorer
2. Click the drop down beside the repo name
3. Click on the Manage repositories...
4. In the Git repositories on the left, select your branch
5. You can deny Contribute to prevent them changing the branch, and you can also deny force push.